# Solution set left unchanged after matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I solve $Tx=0$ where $T$ is some square matrix
then if I multiply both sides by $T$ and solve for $T^2x=0$, will my x be the same?
In other words if I were to multiply to both sides of the equation $Tx=0$ to any order of $T$, will my x be the same? or at least satisfy the first equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,
$$Tx=0\implies T^2x=0\\
T^2x=0\;\;\not\!\!\!\!\implies Tx=0$$
For the first observation, just use that $T$ is linear, and therefore $T(0)=0$:
$$T^2x=T(Tx)=T(0)=0$$
For the second observation, note that a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ may not be surjective, and that moreover, it might be the case that $\mathrm{im}(T)\cap\ker(T)\neq\{0\}$, i.e. $T$ might send some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to something that is itself sent to $0$ by $T$ if $T$ were applied again, but that is not itself $0$. Kevin's answer provides $T=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 0 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ which is a good example of this phenomenon.

Thus, the set of solutions to $T^2x=0$ will **contain** the solutions to $Tx=0$, but it might also contain some things that are **not** solutions to $Tx=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ satisfies $T^2 x=0$ then $x$ satisfies $Tx=0$. The converse is not true.

For example, suppose $T(v,w)=(w,0)$. Then $T^2(v,w)=0$ for any $v,w$ but $T(0,1)=(1,0)\neq 0$. Here $T$ corresponds to 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}